# Yii CGrid pagination and sorting with CArrayDataProvider doesnt work

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel, zii-widgets

I built a custom function in my model and return the raw data:

```
function(){
...
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$rows=$command->queryAll();
return $rows;
}
```

$campModel = $model->function..

I then use those rows in CArrayDataProvider:

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($campModel);
```

Finally i'm trying to view using CGrid:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'bo-campaigns-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$campModel,...
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the way CGrid is paging...but i'm lost
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you're going to use a CArrayDataProvider you need to specifically custom CPagination and Csort objects in its respectively 'sort' and 'pagination' properties.

Comment: I think this is the way...can you please give an example?

Comment: another way will be to use CActiveDataProvider

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new CSort and CPagination objects and assign them to your dataprovider, because CArrayDataProvider doesn't have them defined. Here is an example of CSort creation:

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($campModel);
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->attributes = array(
            'fecha'=>array(
                'asc'=>'dateA DESC',
                'desc'=>'dateA ASC',
            ),
);
$sort->route = 'myController/myMethod';
$dataProvider->sort = $sort;
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='dateA DESC';
```

Comment: Thanks... I think this nailed it :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful suggestion.  Here's a question:  Is it possible to have the sort action reload the grid with ajax instead of reloading the entire page?

Comment: @bjtilley by default CGridView uses ajax updates, unless it detects that javascript is disabled. See reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id' => 'bo-campaigns-grid',
  'dataProvider'=> new CArrayDataProvider($campModel, array(
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 10
        )
    )),
  ...
```

Comment: my bad, forgot to add config to give paging size.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at CSqlDataProvider. Not sure if it would give you the SQL flexibility you need, but it should handle sorting for you more easily than CArrayDataProvider